# Databricks PySpark: Make Dataframe from Rows of Strings

Tags: pyspark

In Azure Databricks using PySpark, I'm reading file names from a directory. I am able to print the rows I need:

```
df_ls = dbutils.fs.ls('/mypath/')
for row in df_ls:
  filename = row.name.lower()
  if 'mytext' in filename:
    print(filename)
```

Outputs, for example:

```
mycompany_mytext_2020-12-22_11-34-46.txt
mycompany_mytext_2021-02-01_10-40-57.txt
```

I want to put those rows into a dataframe but have not been able to make it work. Some of my failed attempts include:

```
df_ls = dbutils.fs.ls('/mypath/')
for row in df_ls:
  filename = row.name.lower()
  if 'mytext' in filename:
    print(filename)
    
#     file_list = row[filename].collect() #tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
#     file_list = filename # last row
#     file_list = filename.collect() # error
#     file_list = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(list(filename)).collect() # breaks last row into list of each character
    
#     col = 'fname' # this and below generates ParseException
#     df = spark.createDataFrame(data = file_list, schema = col)
```

The question is, how do I collect the row output into a single dataframe column with a row per value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can collect the filenames into a list and spark expects a nested list.

the program will be as follows :

```
df_ls = dbutils.fs.ls('/mypath/')

file_names =[]
for row in df_ls:  
  if 'mytext' in row.name.lower():
    file_names.append([row.name])

df = spark.createDataFrame(file_names,['filename'])

display(df)
```